# Mix of Forms auth and Windows auth?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI and a web application, I am wanting to create an auth system where internal users will be able to gain access to the application using their windows auth credentials if they are available, if not I have a form on the webpage that should be used for login.

When I enable windows auth, I get the windows auth popup from browsers, which is not what I want.

Is there a way to check for windows auth without having the windows auth pop-up?

Comment: That's exact Windows authentication. If you don't want the browsers to prompt, follow https://www.lansweeper.com/knowledgebase/enabling-or-disabling-login-prompts/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid the windows auth popup from browsers, the only way is modifying the client side browser setting as lex's provide link.

But I think your mix auth has some issue. If one user doesn't have the domain account, he will not have the permission to access the form auth page or other page.

In my opinion, the right solution is using asp.net [mix auth library](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/OWIN-MixedAuth). By using this OWIN middleware it will implement mixing Windows and Forms Authentication.